# Using Redux-Form in Typescript I would like to use the WrappedFieldProps<S> interface but it isn't exported. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: redux-form, definitelytyped

I'm using Redux-Form and using `<Field>` components that are rendered using functions (as in the sync validation example on the Redux-Form site: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/syncValidation/).

As I'm using Typescript I'd like to give the `renderField` function's parameter a type. The type of the parameter appears to be based on the interface `WrappedFieldProps<S>` however that interface isn't exported so I can't use it.

So am I right to want to use `WrappedFieldProps< S>`, or is there a better way?

Example code:

```
interface RenderFieldProps extends WrappedFieldProps<AppState> {
    placeholder: string,
    type: string,
};

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
            <Field name="email" component={this.renderField} type="text" placeholder="Add your email address"/>
            <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
        </form>
    );
}

private renderField = (props: RenderFieldProps) => (
    <div>
        <input {...props.input} placeholder={props.placeholder} type={props.type}/>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where did you get your type definition, but if you check the index.d.ts in [this repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/redux-form), you will see that WrappedFieldProps is exported in this line:

```
export * from "./lib/Field";
```

So, basically you can import it using:

```
import {WrappedFieldProps } from "redux-form";
```